# Can't refer global variables inside a function (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I'm dealing with a question from [LeetCode #47](https://leetcode-cn.com/problems/permutations-ii/submissions/?utm_source=LCUS&utm_medium=ip_redirect&utm_campaign=transfer2china). The code works just fine but I've got an error I can't figure out why.
In short, `snap` is used to record variable `nums` in every `backtrack`, so that `nums` can be recovered at the end of the function. But once Line 9 is executed, here comes a `'nums' referenced before assignment'` error. However, if I change Line 16 to `nums[:]=snap`, the error is gone.
I know maybe global variable can only be referred rather than assigned without the `global` declaration. But it's still wield because the debugger didn't even execute `nums=snap` in Line 16. How did it know it's a local variable? And if I `global nums`, here comes another error called `name 'nums' is used prior to global declaration`.

```
nums=[1,2,2]
nums.sort()
m=len(nums)
Out=[]
def backtrack(i,snap):
    if i==m :
        Out.append(nums[:])
    else:
        snap=nums[:] #Line 9
        for j in range(i,m):
            if i!=j and nums[j]==nums[i]:
                continue
            else:
                nums[i],nums[j]=nums[j],nums[i]
                backtrack(i+1,nums[:])
        nums=snap #Line 16
backtrack(0,nums[:])
print(Out)
```

Any help would be very appreciated as I'm new in the world of Python :)

Comment: A small part of your question that isn't addressed by the answers in the duplicate is why `nums[:]=snap` works even without `global`. The answer is that `nums[:]=snap` isn't an assignment to the `nums` *variable* - it doesn't *assign a new value* to `nums`; it simply *mutates* the list stored in `nums`.

Comment: Oh, and if you get `name 'nums' is used prior to global declaration`, then just move the `global nums` to the top of your function...

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks a lot. Moving `global nums`  to the top works:)